# Can't set selectionMode in TreeView

Tags: qml, treeview, selection

I am using the TreeView (v2) from the marketplace. I wish to set the 'selectionMode' property in the treeview but this property is not recognized.

How can I set the selectionMode for this TreeView?  Has QQC2 moved selection completely under manual control (i.e. my code has to add/remove items to a SelectionModel?)

Seems strange, particularly since the QAbstractItemModel holds flags for 'selectable'...which come to think of it really belongs with the view

Comment: The docs you are linking to are for the QQC1 version of TreeView, not QQC2.

Comment: You're right.  I can't find any docs that explain how to set selectionMode in QQC2.  (For TreeView 2).  I'll rephrase the question